# Define a class with another class object in Python

Tags: python

So I have a piece of code that goes:

```
current_run = InputFile(foo1, foo2, ... , foo50)
output_file = OutputFile(foo1, foo2, ... , foo50)
```

with the classes being defined as:

```
class InputFile:
   def __init__(self, foo1, foo2, ... , foo50)
   ...

class OutputFile(InputFile):
   ...
```

What I want to do is define `output_file` using `current_run`, e.g., `output_file = OutputFile(current_run)`. But then, `OutputFile` class interprets `current_run` as the `foo` argument. Is there a way to use `current_run` to define `output_file` without copy-pasting the `foo, bar` class arguments?

I don't have much formal CS experience, so please excuse me if it's a silly question.

Edit: I think I originally over-simplified the demo code. My real problem is that the code I'm working with requires a large number of arguments for the classes, which I don't want to copy and paste every time. So I'm looking for a way that these arguments can be inherited.

Comment: Could you include the actual `__init__` methods of both classes?  The most obvious solution is to define a constructor(or a static method) that builds an `OutputFile` from an `InputFile`, but I have a hunch that these don't even need to be two classes in the first place.

Comment: Maybe consider making a `File` class and make both `InputFile` and `OutputFile` be children of the `File` class, as it doesn't really make sense for `OutputFile` to be a child of `InputFile` (in my opinion, anyway)

Comment: Assuming `InputFile.__init__` sets the `foo` and `bar` attributes, you could write `output_file = OutputFile(current_run.foo, current_run.bar)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in practice you could just have a single `File` class (maybe even a single instance, if you want to initialize your output from your input) -- but again, I really want to see some more code before offering that as a solution.

Comment: so my problem is that i got like 50 arguments for the first class, and i don't want to copy paste that into the second class's arguments-- i want a way to copy the first class's arguments into the second class

Comment: How are you making use of these 50 arguments? Are you storing them as instance values? If they are being stored, I would define a base class that handles the 50 arguments in its __init__ and then have the class call other initialization in another function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to settle on which interface you really want.  From what I see here, you want to redefine your OutputFile class to take the InputFile to create:

```
class OutputFile(InputFile):
    def __init__(input_file):
        self.foo = input_file.foo
        self.bar = input_file.bar
```

This presumes that *every* OutputFile instantiation will depend on some InputFile.  Now you use the classes as

```
current_run = InputFile(foo, bar)
output_file = OutputFile(current_run)
```

However, if you *do* have both creation scenarios, then you have a problem to handle both formats.  You need to determine whether you have one argument or two, and adapt accordindgly:

```
class OutputFile(InputFile):
    def __init__(foo_or_input, bar=None):
        if bar:
            self.foo = foo_or_input
            self.bar = bar
        else:
            self.foo = foo_or_input.foo
            self.bar = foo_or_input.bar
```

As with many "detect multiple syntax" implementations, this is a bit ugly.

Comment: Great minds and all. You said "presume", I was originally going to use "pre-suppose" but it didn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do something like that is to define the `__init__` of `OutputFile` to recognize when it has one input parameter:

```
def __init__(self, foo, bar=None):
    if bar is None:
        # Passing in an existing object
        bar = foo.bar
        foo = foo.foo
    super().__init__(foo, bar)
```

You can even avoid the call to `super().__init__` by modifying `InputFile.__init__` directly, instead of adding an unnecessary initializer to `OutputFile`.

Both options assume that you store the inputs `foo` and `bar` somewhere in your object. If not, you will have to generate them from the existing object somehow, or rewrite `__init__` to behave differently in case of a single input.

Answer (score 0):

A more explicit approach would be to create a class method (with the `@classmethod` decorator) that instantiates an `OutputFile` instance from an `InputFile` instance. This avoids having to re-write `OutputFile.__init__` and is more maintainable, imo - you have clear interfaces for initializing an `OutputFile` from scratch or from an `InputFile`.

Example:

```
class InputFile:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar


class OutputFile(InputFile):
    @classmethod
    def from_input_file(cls, input_file):
        return cls(input_file.foo, input_file.bar)


output_file = OutputFile(foo, bar)  # initialized from scratch

current_run = InputFile(foo, bar)
output_file = OutputFile.from_input_file(current_run)  # initialized from an InputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on how you define your class. If you are going to save all the arguments to your functions as an argument list, you should define them as a list.

```
class InputFile(object):
   def __init__(self, *args):
      self._args = args
   ...

class OutputFile(InputFile):
   ...
```

If you store the original args in `_args`, you can put it in the new args like this:

```
current_run = InputFile(foo1, foo2, ... , foo50)
output_file = OutputFile(*current_run._args)
```

The only problem I guess is within the "meat" of your `__init__()` function, you now just have a single `args` value, which you might need to extract afterwards with something like:

```
foo1, foo2, ... foo50 = args
```